# Rails 3 ActiveRecord.. how to join or include tables and get a sum

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, include, inner-join

Here is the relevant data structure and associations:

```
User (has_many completions)
- id

Quest (has_many completions)
- id
- points [amount that earned if completed]

Completions (belongs_to users and quests)
- user_id
- quest_id
```

Basically, Completions is a join table populated when a user completes a quest. The part I am struggling with is how to calculate the total points earned, because it has to reach back to the Quest table to see how much each was worth.

Example:

```
 Quests
  id 1
  points 25
  --
  id 2
  points 10
  --
  id 3
  points 50

 Completions
  user_id 1
  quest_id 1
  --
  user_id 1
  quest_id 2
  --
  user_id 2
  quest_id 3
```

In this example, user_id 1 has earned 35 total points (25+10), and user_id 2 has earned 50 total points.

So two questions:

1) How would I write a query in Rails to allow me to list all users and their total points?

2) Is this the best way to handle this type of functionality?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple to do with a quick `reduce` and a query.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :completions
  has_many :quests, :through => :completions

  attr_accessor :total_points

  # calculates points for individual user
  def points
    @total_points ||= quests.reduce(0) { |sum, quest| sum + quest.points }
    # note this doesn't reload, so if you add a completion without reloading the
    # user object this will be stale
  end

  # when getting a list of users, make sure you use an efficient query to
  # fetch all of the associated quests
  # 
  # this is the same as using `scope :with_quests, include(:quests)`
  def self.with_quests
    include(:quests)
  end
end

# outside of your model:
@users = User.with_quests.all

# and in a view (e.g. _user.html.erb):
Points: <%= user.points %>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Really appreciate the reply! May have a couple issues though. First is "@users = User.with_quest.all" throws "wrong argument type Symbol (expected Module)". Second, unless I am missing something, it does not appear this code is checking only the quests in Completions for that user, is it?

Comment: EDIT: Apparently you don't need the "def self.with_quests" or "User.with_quests.all" pieces.. just doing current_user.points works brilliantly! Thank you so much! I can't say I understand how this knows to look in the Completion table for the right quests though. Is it because of the :through?

Comment: Yeah, your `Completion` model is useless; you really just need a join table named `quests_users` with `quest_id` and `user_id` columns (no model needed) and redefined relationships as `has_and_belongs_to_many :users` and `has_and_belongs_to_many :quests` for quests and users, respectively. I didn't want to spring too many things on you at once.

Comment: As far as the `include(:quests)`, the idea is that your queries are more efficient; without it you have an N+1 problem where you do a query to get the users, then another query for each individual user. Do a read through the Rails Guides to learn more about that. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Comment: Thanks Corey. The Completion table does hold a couple other pieces of data (such as an image), which it why it can't just be a HABTM. However, with some hacking I got the above code to work. Many thanks!